# A theorem similar to Lagrange’s one for infinite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

My textbook *Groups, Matrices, and Vector Spaces - A Group Theoretic Approach to Linear Algebra* by James B. Carrell said that

> It [Lagrange’s theorem] is undoubtedly the most frequently cited elementary result on finite groups.

I would like to ask if there is a theorem that extends the idea of Lagrange’s theorem to the case of infinite group. Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: For any subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ we have $|G| = |H|\cdot|G/H|$, where we are using products of possibly infinite cardinals.

Comment: @Wojowu $|G/H|$ is called the index, right?

Comment: @OmarS Yes. It's usually denoted by $[G:H]$, but I think I've seen this notation restricted to subgroups of finite index so just in case I went with cardinality of quotient.

Comment: There is an interesting observation from a logic standpoint: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256352/is-lagranges-theorem-equivalent-to-ac/257303

Comment: @Wojowu thank you! i recommend you post an answer :)

Comment: @Wojowu: Careful: $[G:H]$ is the index of $H$ in $G$, and denotes the number/cardinal of the set of left (equiv. right) cosets of $H$ in $G$. $G/H$  is *sometimes* used to denote the set of left cosets, but it’s too easy to confuse it with the quotient group, which only makes sense if $H$ is normal. In fact, you talk about “the quotient”, but the quotient is not generally defined.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The quotient group is the same as the set of (left) cosets, except it has additional group structure. Also, $G/H$ is always a quotient in the sense of being the set of orbits under the action of $H$ on $G$ by multiplication from the right.

Comment: @Wojowu: The point is that the quotient group is only defined when $H$ is normal. As I said in my comment, I know that the notation is sometimes used to denote the set of cosets; the point is that it is easy to confuse it with the notation for quotient **group** unless one explicitly says it refers only to the set of cosets/orbits.  The notation $[G:H]$ is not, contrary to your impression, restricted to the finite index case. Also compare “*the* quotient” (singular definite article implying a specific structure) with “*a* quotient” (indefinite article).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is @Wojowu's comment that answers my question. I post it here to remove this question from unanswered list. All credits are given to @Wojowu.

> For any subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ we have $|G| = |H|\cdot|G/H|$, where we are using products of possibly infinite cardinals.